# Are kriging questions getting enough attention?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Personally, I am very unlikely to attempt to answer or judge a question tagged [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) because I do not have those skills and interests, but I have noticed that many of them are going unanswered.

I did a quick manual count just now and, since last September, of the 17 posted only 3 have an answer.

I *think* that many/most of them may be low quality but only one of them has been closed.

Is anyone with [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) skills and interests able to perform a review of these questions to see if it is the same or similar questions coming up repeatedly, and thus might be redirectable as duplicates of our most [frequently asked kriging questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging?sort=frequent)?

Comment: Very interesting observation: thank you for bringing this up.  I look forward to reading the community's thoughts.  In the meantime I have shared some thoughts with you in the moderator chat room.

Comment: @whuber Your mod chat room thoughts were spot on and I agree that the community's thoughts are needed here.

Comment: I think part of the problem is how many are specifically about the math/method or appropriateness of Kriging and may well be more suited to cross-validated. As some of @whuber's comments on those questions have pointed out, there's a lot that goes into deciding to use it and understanding the data (and statistics) enough to understand that choice and its ramifications, while the GIS software just implements it. Personally, the stats focused ones are beyond me. There are questions specific to the GIS tools and implementations that are perfectly well suited here, but it can be a fine line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statistic part of kriging is more tough than the geo part, which explains many unanswered questions.

Reading the newest posts I did see interesting ones and I plan to go through more. Some questions I visited had common content, but were not duplicates (e.g.: [a1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124243/how-to-deal-with-data-which-are-not-normally-distributed-when-kriging#comment204458_124243)-[a2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74015/empirical-bayesian-kriging-does-data-need-to-be-normal), [b1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129723/kriging-forest-biomass/141140#141140)-[b2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133283/kriging-metal-concentration-with-irregular-set-of-sample-points)).

I edited some kriging questions for readability, which I think might increase chances of receiving answers. I'm not specialist in geostatistics, but very interested in it.

**Edit:**

I've finished going through all [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) questions. I was able to improve many of them with edits, including voting on questions and answers to highlight useful content. I also added comments linking related questions. Some of them were answered, some were closed, some marked as duplicates. I also tagged former `title:kriging -[kriging] closed:0` questions properly.

Some questions seems to be very hard to answer (the challenge is launched)!

When PolyGeo posted this question, the unanswered rate of [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) was greater than 40%. Now it is smaller than 30% (similarly to [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) and [javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), for example).

Comment: Thanks!  Your efforts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: (update). All kriging questions (as per answer) until today were revised.

Comment: That's a great way to celebrate the 100th [tag:kriging] question!

Comment: I am pretty solid on Kriging and my answers to many Kriging questions  (i), why are you kriging, and (2) I can tell from the question the user is not ready to conduct kriging and the question is essentially teach me kriging.  I do not even teach it an undergraduate anymore as many GIS students do not have the statistical background.