# How many tags for kriging interpolation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have just read a question tagged [cokriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cokriging), and this tag currently has only two questions under it.

I paid attention into this subject because I had previously helped curating the [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) tag (see: [Are kriging questions getting enough attention?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/are-kriging-questions-getting-enough-attention/3920#3920)). When reviewing posts tagged 'kriging' many of them were about ordinary kriging, but there were also questions about regression kriging, universal kriging, simple kriging and also co-kriging (just use a simple search with [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) + keyword to see it).

Now, I wonder if it is worth having all types of kriging under one umbrella (the [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) tag) or having specific tags for each type of kriging. What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer keeping just one tag, as time has proved it is by far the most used terminology in form of tags in GIS SE. Also because all types of kriging are related to each other, and because 'kriging' is not currently a subject we have many questions in, hence, we don't need this much level of detail.

With just one tag for all types of kriging it is easier to keep consistency in tagging, making it easier to find duplicates too.

Therefore, I suggest making [co-kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-kriging) a synonym of [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging) and if tags such as [regression-kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression-kriging) appears, then, make it a synonym as well.

Comment: I have made co-kriging a synonym of kriging. If regression-kriging comes up, I suggest making a similar post here on meta to make it a synonym as well. Thanks for your efforts in curating the kriging tag.